# Projection of 3D convex hull onto xy plane with a colour map

Tags: python, projection, triangulation, convex-hull, contourf

What I'd like at the end is the smoothed colour map with contours plotted on top of it. The idea is to preserve as much as possible information from the 3D convex hull.

The problem is that the code I developed so far doesn't work for all the inputs.

Example

If I set tricontourf() integer parameter let say to 8 and provide 10 input files I will get 8 plots which are OK but 2 will be solid colour.
Next if I change parameter to 9 I'll get 7 good and 3 odd. Some of the good ones from the first step are now wrong!

Ideally I'd like to have this parameter fixed at ~25 so the colour map is smoothed.

Have look at the pictures:

[This is wrong, int parameter = 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwZVT.png)

[this is what I want but smoother, int parameter 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOZwA.png)

What is important to me is to have triangulation based on the convex hull.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys, os, time, math
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# get covex hull data and save them to an array
cvx = []
dataX = []
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:

    X = np.genfromtxt(filename,delimiter="", skip_header=2)
    dataX.append(X)
    hull = ConvexHull(X)
    cvx.append(hull)


for idx,filename in enumerate(sys.argv[1:]):

    # start plotting data
    x, y, z = dataX[idx].T

    # triangulation based on a convex hull
    simpl = cvx[idx].simplices
    tri = Triangulation(x, y, triangles=simpl)

    # plot lines (triangles)    
    plt.triplot(tri, color='k')

    # plot contour lines based on convex hull facets
    plt.tricontour(x, y, z, 5, linewidths=0.5, colors='k', triangles=simpl)
    # plot colour map 
    plt.tricontourf(x, y, z, 8, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow, triangles=simpl)

    plt.show()
```